# How to set a matrice with a complex nested tupled list

Tags: for-loop, numpy, matrix, group-by, tuples

I have a nested tupled list that looks like this

```
nested_ls =   [[(0, (0, 0)), (1, (1, 1)), (2, (2, 2)), (1, (1, 3))], [(3, (3, 3)), (2, (2, 4)), (4, (4, 0)), (3, (3, 1))], [(3, (3, 5)), (2, (2, 6)), (3, (3, 7)), (3, (3, 8))]]
```

I wish to set the matrice "m" with two items from each tuple; the first item, item1, is each item in the outer tuple [ [(item1(0,0)), (item1(1,1)][ ....(item1(3,5))....] ..] and the second item, item2, is on indexposition [1] in each inner tuple, for instance (3(3,item2)).

I've tried to loop with groupby iterator as follows:

```
from numpy  import *
from itertools import groupby
     for i,j in groupby(nested_ls, lambda x: x):
      for j in i:
          print j # item1 in outer tuple
          l = j[1] # inner tuple
          m[i,j] = i[j-1][1],i[j][1]] +=1 #matrice m, [j-1] is to get item1 in outer tuple
      return m                             
                                        # and i[j][1] is to get indexposition [1] in inner tuple
```

The resulting matrice should look something like

```
[0 1 0 0 1]
[0 1 1 0 1]
[0 0 0 1 0]
```

where each 1 stands for an occurence of item1*item2 in nested_ls.

```
            inner tuple, item2
             0  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
   outer   0 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
   tuple   1 [0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
   item1   2 [0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
           3 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1]
           4 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: I don't quite get it. What do the terms `(a, (b, c))` each mean in the original tuples? And the matrix should look something like that or exactly like that?

Comment: The items are ID numbers for tokens in a dataset. I'm trying to set the array with a and c from each tuple. For each occurence it should add +=1. The plotted resulting matrice doesn't have to look exactly as  plotted above, it should show 1, or at least 1, on the places in the matrix that corresponds to the places in the nested_list where a and c co- occur.

Comment: Sorry I this still isn't 100% clear. Are `b` and `c` the indices? What exactly do you mean by `a` and `c` co-occurring? And why does your list contain two lists each of which contain tuples, rather than simply having a list of tuples? Does this have significance?

Comment: For instance, in the tuple  (3(a), (3, 5(c))) and if a with the value 3 and c as the value 5 occur one, then +1 in the matrice, if twice, that is, nested_ls contains (3(a), (3, 5(c)))(3(a), (3, 5(c))) than 2 in the column in the matrice, and so on. This should be generated if the loop variables i,j  in i[j-1][1],i[j][1]] are set correctly just that I'm not quite sure of how to define it. The first part i[j-1][1] should be row in the matrice..

Comment: and row 1, and the second part is i[j][1] should be the column 1 in the row and [j-1] should start the loop from row 0 instead of 1 but it doesn't work with the loop I've made above.

Comment: _"The plotted resulting matrice doesn't have to look exactly as plotted above"_ So the matrix you gave above isn't the actual expected output of the tuples you gave? Can you provide the exact output you expect to see, not what it "should look something like"?

Comment: I've posted it below now.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to create a 2-d array where each 1 value corresponds to a coordinate given in your `nested_ls` structure. You can do that with code like this:

```
nested_ls =   [
[(0, (0, 0)), (1, (1, 1)), (2, (2, 2)), (1, (1, 3))],
[(3, (3, 3)), (2, (2, 4)), (4, (4, 0)), (3, (3, 1))],
[(3, (3, 5)), (2, (2, 6)), (3, (3, 7)), (3, (3, 8))]
]

#extract coordinates from nested structure
coordinates = [(a, c) for l in nested_ls for a, (b, c) in l]

#construct empty matrix.
width  = 1 + max(c for a,c in coordinates)
height = 1 + max(a for a,c in coordinates)
matrix = [[0 for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]

#populate matrix
for a, c in coordinates:
    matrix[a][c] += 1

#display matrix
for row in matrix:
    print row
```

(Sorry I'm using ordinary lists instead of a numpy matrix - I don't have that library installed. I assume the basic principles are the same, though.)

Result:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```